# How to find and modify an asp.net control with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This has been bothering me for quite some time. I'm simply trying to change the value of a textbox defined in asp.net, which normally works when it is not within a LoggedInTemplate.

I've searched everywhere on the net and even here, but the only thing I can find close to doing what I need is here [Finding an asp:button and asp:textbox in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024954/finding-an-aspbutton-and-asptextbox-in-javascript). Unfortunately that doesn't work. Here's what I have so far:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
  <script src="../../scripts/webeffects.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
</head>
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
  <LoggedInTemplate>
  <div class="lotto_pick_container">
    <table runat="server" id="tblLottoPick">
      <tr><th colspan="3">Pick a Lotto Number</th></tr>
  <tr>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txt1stNum" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txt2ndNum" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txt3rdNum" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><asp:Button ID="cmdSubmitPick" runat="server" Text="Submit Lotto Number" 
        onclientclick="return validateLottoPicks()" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
  </div>
  </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

Right now I'm trying to use an external js script to find a textbox and modify it with an arbitrary value of 12, just so that I know it can work:

```
function validateLottoPicks() {
  document.getElementById('<%= LoginView1.FindControl("txt2ndNum").ClientID %>').value = 12
}
```

When I debug this with Firebug it seems all my other code works, except for this one function. I have verified the function gets called, it's just this line that doesn't work. Can someone please provide some guidance? I'll send milk and cookies.

**Update:**

Thanks for all the help from everyone. This was my first time using Stack Overflow and I was definitely impressed by the quick responses.


It turns out my actual problem was that using **<%= LoginView1.FindControl("txt2ndNum").ClientID %>** does not work in external js scripts. I didn't know this. Once, I put the function in the header of my page everything worked. Now I'm going to avoid using ASP.NET controls because I don't want to deal with that again, and it makes more sense if I ever decide to use something other than ASP.NET.

Comment: What ID is output to the script?  What ID does the control actually get?  What error is raised?

Comment: Don't hack the ASP.NET ViewState on the client using javascript. Either use ASP.NET controls or use HTML inputs and `Form.Request`

Comment: @Raynos I didn't know that what I am trying to do is considered hacking ViewState. Really, I'm just trying to do some client-side validation to save trips to the server. Is my whole approach wrong?

Comment: clientside validation is fine. ASP.NET is notorious for not remembering state changes made in JavaScript once server side controls get to the server. Btw your approach is wrong, your using ASP.NET ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have set `visible=false` on this line

```
<table runat="server" id="tblLottoPick" visible="false">
```

From that moment the controls are not rendered the javascript can not find this control. If you do not wish to show this table use css, for example `style="display:none;"` so its rendered but not visible. All the rest seems to me that working.

### Update

From the comments also seems that this code is not inside the aspx page, so the ClientID can not work and not found. Add this somewhere in the header in the page that have this LoginView1 control.

```
function validateLottoPicks() {
  document.getElementById('<%= LoginView1.FindControl("txt2ndNum").ClientID %>').value = 12
}
```

Comment: Good catch.  I didn't even see the visible="false" property.

Comment: I removed the visible="false" and it still doesn't work. I'm getting this message in Firebug: TypeError: document.getElementById("<%= tblLottoPick.FindControl(\"txt2ndNum\").ClientID %>") is null

Comment: @Peter Where are you have place the <%= tblLottoPick.FindControl(\"txt2ndNum\").ClientID %>, because seems that you have includ it on JS and is not render it !

Comment: @Peter you need to add the <%= tblLottoPick.FindControl("txt2ndNum").ClientID %> inside the aspx page. !

Comment: I added this to the header and it still doesn't work. Regardless, shouldn't it work anyway, I'm using an external script?

Comment: @Peter if you get the error document.getElementById("<%= tblLottoPick.FindControl(\"txt2ndNum\").ClientID %>") is null  then seems that the script is not run because you do not get the real clientID.

Comment: I used the rendered id as per Trevor's suggestion below, id="LoginView1_txt2ndNum", and it grabs the value through my external script, so the script is running.

Comment: I see what you mean. I came across another article where the person had the problem with the variable being populated with the literal "<%= tblLottoPick.FindControl(\"txt2ndNum\").ClientID %>"

This is only the case for external scripts though. I tried your suggestion at the top of the page and it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

`tblLottoPick.FindControl("txt2ndNum").ClientID` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this into a javascript string variable.  What are you getting?

'<%= LoginView1.FindControl("txt2ndNum").ClientID %>'

Because you shouldn't have to do that.  Can you just do this?

document.getElementById('txt2ndNum')

Also, check in firebug to see what the ID value is set to for that control (i.e. the rendered textbox).  I mean see what it's rendered as.  You just need to get the right id.

Comment: I get: 
id="LoginView1_txt2ndNum" and 
name="LoginView1$txt2ndNum"

Comment: Ok. And can you find a control in the DOM called "LoginView1_txt2ndNum"?  Are you sure it exists?  Because I think it might be rendering as 'txt2ndNum'.

Comment: I tried this and it does exist! I managed to capture the value using the id without the LoginView1.FindControl